# NSPopover crashes when window closes

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nswindow, nspopover

Long story short:

If I put a `NSTableView` with highlight style set to SourceList inside a `NSPopover`, my app crashes when I close the window containing the popover.

EDIT: I can replicate this issue on a new project.
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7968745/PopoverFail.zip

Long story:

I have a very strange issue.
Currently debugging with `NSZombie` seems to lead the problem to a `NSPopover`, but I'm not completely sure because I cannot replicate it in a new project.

I have a `NSWindow` and its controller which creates a `NSViewController` and its view (everything created with IB).
In this view there is a button which opens a popover.
This popover has a simple `NSTableView` with style set to SourceList. The popover is transient.

If I open the popover, and directly close the window everything is ok.
If I open the popover, change focus to a textfield in the window (so that the popover closes) and then close the window, the app crashes.

Enabling zombie I see the following log

> *** -[NSPopoverFrame _subviewGeometryChanged:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1005ce3d0

If I profile with `NSZombie` this is the stack:

[image: Instrument stack]

I can replicate the issue every time. I've change now the style of the table view to regular and the crash does not happen anymore (but I lost the translucent effect on yosemite.

I don't know what can be the problem, and if it is really the table view / popover combination

EDIT:
More information:
I'm using ARC.
The issue arises at the deallocation of the window.
I removed all the code of the application except the one needed to open the window. The crash happens also in this case.

EDIT: I can replicate this issue on a new project.
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7968745/PopoverFail.zip

I'll also open a bug report to Apple

Comment: Are you using ARC? Is your `NSTableView` being deallocated?

Comment: I'm using ARC. Table view is created in IB, and I have a weak pointer to it in my view controller

Answer (score 0):

Based off your comment reply; this is an issue with your `NSPopover` being deallocated before `subviewGeometryChanged` gets called.  I don't know when it does get called, but when it does it is expecting your `NSPopover` to exist.

A good analogy that is commonly used balloons.  A strong reference is a person holding onto a balloon, while also pointing at it.  A weak reference is a person just pointing at a balloon being held by somebody else.  So if the weak reference is pointing at this balloon, and the person holding it lets go, then the weak reference will be pointing at `nil`.

Try changing your `NSPopover` property to be of type (strong) and see if that fixes it for you

Comment: Usually if an object is created in the `nib`, is the responsibility of the `nib` to keep a strong reference to it. And to avoid cycles the `IBOutlet` is usually `weak`. Anyway I tried to change it to `strong` and it did not solve the problem. I'm starting to thing the problem is somewhere else...

Comment: Ah sorry, I wasn't thinking fully you're right.  Can you try implementing the `NSWindowDelegate` method, `windowWillClose`-- then setting a break point in there and seeing what the value of your NSPopover is?

Comment: Yes. Now with the test project is very easy :) . The popover is not nil at that point. It seems like some notifications or methods are not properly handled by the popover at deallocation.

Comment: Cool ^^  do you know why they aren't being handled properly?  I'm just curious now

Comment: This is why I opened this question :) :p I hope Apple will answer to my bug report

Comment: Any update on that from Apple or from you? I hit a similar problem and have trouble finding a solution to this. Thank you for the connection to Source-List highlighting, it didn't spring tot my mind, based on the Zombie result.

Comment: Try setting NSTableView's datasource delegate to be nil when the popover is dealloced?

Comment: @JacobGorban still nothing from Apple.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not able to reproduce the error with your project, but as I was having a similar issue I thought I’d post a reply (and possible solution). If a popup window is open and you close the window it's attached to, you need to clean things up in the view’s `dealloc` method. This is what I did:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    if (self.thePopover.shown) {
        [self.thePopover close]; // forces the popover to close w/o consulting the delegate
        self.thePopover.delegate = nil;
        self.thePopover = nil;
    }
}
```

This might be hitting the problem with a sledgehammer (why would I need to set the delegate to `nil` if `close` won’t call it?), but it solved the crashing problem for me.

Comment: I've just tried again I am not able to verify it anymore. Maybe they fixed the problem (without acknowledge it on the bug report). I'm curious if there is anybody with OS X 10.2 (and Xcode 6.1.1 and related OS X SDK) to test it.